# How to display multiple matches from cti search within unified service desk(USD)

Tags: unified-service-desk

I'm trying to configure Microsoft Unified Service Desk(USD) for use with CTI.
I have already configured generic listener with cti search and window navigation rules. It works for single match and no match scenario.

But I am unable to display multiple matched results. Is it possible to show these records without developing my own hosted control?

[image: multiple matches]

Thanks

Gregor

Answer (score 0):

No. USD can only load a single-match result from your CTI Searches. It is very common for a USD CTI to require some custom Hosted Control development in order to attain the desired functionality here.